# Exactly for whom was the dog parceled in Hachi: A Dog's Tale?

Tags: plot-explanation, hachi-a-dogs-tale

In the movie **Hachi: A Dog's Tale** we have seen in the beginning of the movie that dog was being parceled. So whom it was parceled to and why didn't the owner for whom it was parceled bother to search for it? So was there some other ***significance which I missed*** in the movie?

Comment: This movie is based on a true story. I did not see the movie, but for the real story they never found out who was the first owner of the dog and why they did not search for him. So i guess this has no relevance for the story they tell, at least when they concentrate on telling the real story without much additional Inventions : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachik%C5%8D

Comment: In the actual story, the professor was the first owner of the dog.   It was not sent to someone else, got lost and was found by the professor.   That part is introduced only in the American version.   Perhaps they thought that it is a nice way to account for the presence of an original Japanese Akita puppy on the platform of a small town train station in New England.

Answer (score 2):

In the movie the dog escaped from the train. Depending on where the dog was sent from and when the dog was declared missing from his package the search area could be immense. Furthermore the owners probably could have filed an insurance claim and gotten a new dog for free. That's definitely easier than searching for a missing puppy around potentially hundreds of miles of track.

Answer (score 1):

At the start, when the label on the puppy carrier gets torn, you get a brief glimpse of the address.  The puppy was being sent to a person (perhaps) named Stephen Towers and his address was 121 Jordan Ave, Bedridge, RI 02895.  Bedridge appears to be a small town, so if the person was still there, he would have seen the fliers.  Therefore, I would guess that he had already left the place at the time the puppy was sent to him from Japan.